# How can I reduce correlation between two independents variable?

Tags: regression, correlation, variance, variability, variable

Edvard, the evaluator in sample B, does not know Richard, the target subject in sample A. However, the two, independently, give the same answer/Likert value (1-5) to 30% of the questionnaire items. It results in an artificial inflation of the correlation between the evaluations. How can I reduce it?